# These question should flags as duplicate or not?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

These question should flags as duplicate or not?

[Why isn't lxterminal installed when installing lxde-core?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363357/why-isnt-lxterminal-installed-when-installing-lxde-core)

[When a package recommends A or B, which one is installed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364481/when-a-package-recommends-a-or-b-which-one-is-installed)